# Comparison of view.setOnLongClickListener and view.onClick in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I'm trying to call another function from my recycler view adapter, I add the onclick listener in my `holder.itemView`. I have tried `setOnClickListener` and `onClick` in my Activity with `this@MainActivity` as the `context` paramater, it works fine.

```
btn.setOnClickListener { showDialog(this@MainActivity) }
btn.onClick { showDialog(this@MainActivity) }
```

but `onClick` won't work in the adapter because

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    showDialog(context, notes[position])
} // This works fine

// Type mismatch required Context, Found CoroutineContext
holder.itemView.onClick { showDialog(context, notes[position]) }
```

What should I do to fix this if I want to use `onClick` instead of setOnClickListener

Comment: from where do you get context, which you passing incase of holder.itemView.onClick {showDialog(context, notes[position]) } ?

Comment: I get the context from constructor in my adapter `class NotesAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
class NotesAdapter(private val ctx: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {
    // Etc
    holder.itemView.onClick { showDialog(ctx, notes[position]) }
}
```

**EDIT - Explanation**

I'm not an expert at Kotlin by any means, but the error that you got was a very clear clue as to what was going on.

When you call `holder.itemView.onClick` under the hood you are calling itemView.setOnClickListener which takes an instance of View.OnClickListener. So you could have done something like this and it probably would have worked fine:

```
class NotesAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {
    // Etc
    holder.itemView.onClick(View.OnClickListener(){
        void onClick(v: View) {
            showDialog(context, notes[position])
        }
    })
}
```

Instead you wanted to use some of Kotlins clean syntax and pass it a lambda. Which is completely valid, and much cleaner. However, it seems like the lambda (or coroutine) has apparently also has a field called context and it has a type of CoroutineContext. Continuing the example above its the equivalent of this:

```
holder.itemView.onClick(View.OnClickListener(){
    var context: CoroutineContext
    void onClick(v: View) {
        showDialog(context, notes[position])
    }
})
```

In which case when you call showDialog you get the "context" of the current scope which is the wrong type which is why you got the Type mismatch error.

In java there's another solution, I just don't know the equivalent Kotlin syntax. You would do something like this:

```
holder.itemView.onClick { showDialog(NotesAdapter.this.context, notes[position]) }
```

Which is just another way of telling the compiler that the context that you are looking for is in the NotesAdapter scope and not in the Coroutine scope

Comment: Can you give me an explanation of why this approach works?